# Read preferences on firefox startup?

Tags: firefox-addon

my addon needs to connect to a remote service (via ajax). I'd like to do this as soon as possible but I need a username and password preference stored in the Mozilla preferences-service.

Can anybody tell me, which is the best way to access those properties as early as possible after firefox startup?

I tried to get the preferences-service in a callback method for window.load, but it seems that the service is not yet available!

Another idea would be to connect on demand and store the connection in a singleton or static member variable - but I would prefer to do an initial connection setup!

Thanks in advance,
Daniel.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to get the preferences service? It's definitely available long before your window load handler is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to get the preferences-service in a callback method for window.load, but it seems that the service is not yet available!

That's not correct and you should look for the error source elsewhere. The preferences (and all the other data stored in the user profile) are definitely available when the first browser window loads. In fact, they are already available when the [`profile-after-change` notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications) is sent which is way earlier in the startup process.